# Update table A, Insert into table B with one SQL command?

Tags: mysql, coldfusion, insert

I'm trying to find a way to update table A with a boolean value and then create a record in table B (if the boolean in table A is false) in the same SQL statement in my MySQL database, is this possible? Or, do I need to create two different statements?

My current logic goes like this:

```
SELECT tbl_a.vendor_code, tbl_a.vendor_name, tbl_a.has_page 
FROM tbl_a 
WHERE tbl_a.vendor_code = 'myvendorcode'
```

If the above query returns false on `tbl_a.has_page` then I want to update the record to be true

```
UPDATE tbl_a 
SET tbl_a.has_page = true 
WHERE tbl_a.vendor_code = 'myvendorcode'
```

then, I want to create a new record in `tbl_b` with the `vendor_code` and `vendor_name` inserted into the corresponding columns in my new record.

I'm using ColdFusion and can make use of `<cftransaction>` to keep in touch with the DB if I want to use a few statements but, I was wondering if there was a way to do it in one statement.

Comment: No, this is not possible; you have to create two statements

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two options:

1. Multiple Statements
2. Trigger

The problem with multiple statements is that if you run an update or insert from *outside* your application, then your business rules won't be honored. If you make these changes via a trigger, then it doesn't matter if the modifications come from your application, or a query ran directly against the database, your business logic will always be honored.

Comment: thanks for including the logic behind the two options. I suspect trigger will be the most effective means of achieving my goal. Also, thanks for cleaning up my question.

Answer (score 3):

You will need either two statements or a [trigger](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/triggers.html) to do this.

Answer (score 1):

RedFilter's answer of a trigger is the best, imo. One alternative: Does your version of MySQL support stored procedures? You could fire one statement (e.g. the stored proc) which would then execute the internal calls. Not ideal, but possible.